# Destroy back button event- android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, event-listener

I created the following event to Android's Back button (`PhoneGap` 2.2.0):

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    //Do Something
}, false);
```

I have the following link that takes me to an external site from application

My Link

I override the back button event and as soon as I pass inside the app to another link the event is not canceled.. and since another link not know cordova he can not even access to this event.

So I have to cancel it completely!

How I do it...?

When I press the back button I get the following error message in the log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at :1
```

and nothing happens ..

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want my event will not work anymore after a certain function ran

Comment: If you vote down mean that is inferior question, is not it? So why no one answers it?

Comment: A vote down (as shown by the hover text) normally means that not much effort has been put into researching the problem before posting it here, for example, you haven't said what you've tried, where you've looked, or anything else. You just posted your problem and expected answers

Comment: If I did not say mean I did not find anything about it! If someone does not know the answer does not mean that the question is not good ..

Comment: Post the code where you have overridden onBackPressed() method

Comment: HodayaShalom - Here on SO, there is always someone who knows the answer, you just either need to do some digging, or write a very good question. As it stands, myself and @ShreyaShah are trying, and I would have suggested the same answer that Shreya gave but she beat me to it, which implies that (as we have both stated), your question isn't clear. We're just trying to help, both you answer the question, and learn what you should be doing when posting your questions in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onBackKey() {
    console.log("I've caught a back key");

    // We are going back to home so remove the event listener
    // so the default back key behaviour will take over
    document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);

    // Hide the current dive and show home
    document.getElementById(cur).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('home').style.display = 'block';    
    cur = 'home';
}

function goToDiv(id) {
    // We are moving to a new div so over ride the back button
    // so when a users presses back it will show the home div
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);

    // Hide home and show the new div
    document.getElementById('home').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    cur = id;
}
```

place html tags

```
 <div id="home">Back Button Home<br/><a href="javascript:goToDiv('div1')">Div One</a><br/><a href="javascript:goToDiv('div2')">Div Two</a></div>
```

Please find below link for the detailed answer

https://gist.github.com/955496

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, finally an answer to my question! This is the line I needed: document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as

```
boolean toRun = true;

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    if (toRun)    
    {
        //Do Something
        toRun = false;
    }
});
```

Set the boolean as per your need. And check, if its first time, executr code. Else do nothing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to cancel the event completely it is not possible?

Comment: @HodayaShalom, What exactly do u mean by "cancel the event completely"? If you want it to be cancelled after some particular function call, you can set it to false in last line of that function

Comment: I mean destroy this event.. As if he did not exist before. I want that Button back will return to its normal operation

Comment: @HodayaShalom, If you do nothing in else part, it will work as per expected. You can call super.onBackPressed(); in else to be sure

Comment: If I do nothing on the else part, the back button does its normal operation?

Comment: But I have to cancel the event completely because I go inside the app to another link and the event overrides my back button and he can not return to the application later

Comment: @HodayaShalom, What does it do? Still executes event listener's code?

Comment: I override the back button event and as soon as I pass inside the app to another link the event is not canceled.. and since another link not know cordova he can not even access to this event.

Comment: @HodayaShalom, I think you need to put some more code. Relavant to omBackPressed(). And please specify what exactly you want to do in your edited question. I am getting confused